# Setting variables on git remote repository - git gc doesn't run automatically

Tags: git, variables, git-gc

It seems that git refuse to do gc command automatically on my remote repository. In about one month that repository enlarge to about 6GB because of .pack files. I think that is problem with variable gc.auto - how can I set this variable on remote repsoitory, or how can I run git-gc command by hand on that repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to log in on the box where your remote repo is hosted and then simply type

```
git gc
```

on the command line.

Regarding `gc.auto`: the [docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) say:

> gc.auto
>    When there are approximately more than this many loose objects in the repository, git gc --auto will pack them. Some Porcelain commands use this command to perform a light-weight garbage collection from time to time. The default value is 6700. Setting this to 0 disables it.

However, you are talking about `.pack` files. Seems like there's another option dealing with that:

> gc.autopacklimit
>    When there are more than this many packs that are not marked with *.keep file in the repository, git gc --auto consolidates them into one larger pack. The default value is 50. Setting this to 0 disables it.

Note that `gc.autopacklimit` works on the number of packs, not their sizes. Maybe you could tweak the `gc` behavior using these...

Answer (score 0):

Note: if your repo has only one pack file, a `git gc` should *not* repack on `git config gc.autoPackLimit 1`. Yet it did.
That is, it did until Git 2.10 (Q3 2016).

See [commit 5f4e3bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f4e3bf536621675efd51020eb2950986b882e18) (25 Jun 2016) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 97865e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97865e83c7266ad0fd55f75ae4e2d968ef34bf6f), 13 Jul 2016)</sup>

> ### `gc`: fix off-by-one error with `gc.autoPackLimit`

This matches the documentation and allows `gc.autoPackLimit=1` to maintain a single pack without attempting a repack on every "`git gc --auto`" invocation.

> "`gc.autoPackLimit`" when set to 1 should not trigger a repacking when there is only one pack, but the code counted poorly and did so.